# How do I make my browser application the default application in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I recently made a browser for iOS in Xcode using Swift. I can't seem to find documentation or code that allows my users to make my iOS application their default browser in settings, like you can for Brave, DuckDuckGo, et al.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am honestly confused as to why you would think it is not... How else do you make a browser a default option when it is currently not the default option using Xcode? Whichever way you slice it, you will have to use code to rectify this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL:DR** If you are not intending to put that "browser" on the AppStore then you probably can't.

Your Applications will need to take the new Managed Entitlement `default-browser-requests@apple.com` as well as apply at apple for a new "default app" via email: `default-app-requests@apple.com`

Have a look at this post over at Apple Developer Forums [Making an app that can be set the default web browser](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650027)

Comment: Browser is already on the Apple App Store. Just wanted users to be able to make it a default option like my competitors. I figured this had to be a plist/entitlement issue. For some reason, I could not find what you were able to find - through what I'm guessing was a simple search? This is the correct answer. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. If its the correct answer then consider accepting it :)